Is there any point in setting `fp16_full_eval=True` if training in `fp16`?
I train a Huggingface model with fp16=True, e.g.:
    training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./results",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=4e-5,
    lr_scheduler_type="cosine",
    per_device_train_batch_size=32,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,
    num_train_epochs=3,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    fp16=True,
)

Is there any point in also setting fp16_full_eval=True? Or is that already implied by fp16=True?
Same question for bf16.


Is there any point in also setting fp16_full_eval=True?

fp16=True only controls the precision during the training, and not during eval or inference. fp16_full_eval=True forces the eval or inference mode to use the half-precision fp16 format, instead of mixed precision (set by default internally using Automated Mixed Precision or AMP). This leads to less precise, smaller tensors, and hence, a drastically smaller memory footprint. In some cases, it can be a source of pesky CUDA run-time errors, but if your model trains and evals without errors, it can be an extremely fruitful memory optimization, without much loss in model performance.

Or is that already implied by fp16=True?

It is not. You can set both fp16 and fp16_full_eval to True for mixed precision training and full fp16 precision evaluation. Note that this might adversely affect the metric calculations due to lower precision.
The same considerations apply to bf16 and bf16_full_eval. It is worth noting that bf16 has worse precision, but better stability than fp16.
Source: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.15.0/en/performance#fp16-inference
